# How ca I enable port to be accessible on public ip

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, iptables

I have Ubuntu server I am trying to the port 8550 to be accessible on the server public IP address, I can hit the web service running on that port from the server itself but not from the public IP address.

running this `netstat -anltp | grep "8550"`

the output is 
`tcp  0    0   127.0.0.1:8550  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  23961/python`

Does this look right or the IP address should be 0.0.0.0:8550 if so how can I achieve that

What should I add to the iptables (I guess) in order to enable this port publicly

Thanks

Comment: Is the server connected to a router where the port is being blocked?

Comment: Thanks John, resolved already I did a silly mistake answer is below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out

My mistake that my python service was listening to port 8550 on localhost.

To solve this issue I changed localhost to 0.0.0.0 and that resolves the issue